# Visual studio 2015 First Ionic Application issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am new in Ionic,I have installed Ionic project template, android sdk and select a new ionic tab and also use below code:

npm install -g cordova ionic

Project Folder as below :[image]

After then select Android and run project but is gives below screen.

[image]

I dont know what to do next, I have also install task runer.

Thanks.

Comment: The instructions are there on the screen: install the __npm task runner__. I don't know what you mean with "install run tasker" . Be precise, this is the core of the question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman,  I have already run task runner but also got above screen.

Comment: You should not "run task runner" but "install the NPM Task Runner extension". There are 2 links there, did you click them?

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Yes I haves install it but same error.